# Understanding 人は常に、その人唯一の存在でございますれば

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 言葉とは裏腹にテレザの声は冷たい。雪の女王のような面差しが、今は真実凍りつくようだ。
>
> 貴方の前ではそうとしか在れないとテレザは言って、そう在ってほしいと自分は望んだ。
>
> 許される幻影など、自分には永劫相応しくないから。
>
> 「代わりにはなり得ません。誰も彼も。**人は常に、その人唯一の存在でございますれば**」
>
> フレデリカが淡々と言う。
>
> 「それでも、人は清算を求めるものであろ。それがどのような形であれ」

86─エイティシックス─Ep.2 ─ラン・スルー・ザ・バトルフロント─〈上〉 安里アサト

How should I understand the bold sentence? Is it equivalent to, say, 他の人にとっては、その人が常に唯一の存在であるので?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are right. Basically it says '(I) cannot be a replacement. Nobody. **Because a person is always a unique existence**''.

I feel その人 is a bit wrongly inserted, but it can be understood as being used in the same way as その人独自 'his/her unique/original'. So more literally その人唯一の存在 is *her original, unique existence*.

Answer (score 2):

ございますれば is a double punch of archaic speech. First, polite ます's 仮定形, ますれば is effectively obsolete, as we don't insert a polite marker in a clause led by れば. When a politer conditional is needed, we use ましたら instead. Second, the れば is not "if" but a remnant of old 已然形 sense "since, because". [The dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%B0/#jn-172830) says:

> **４** 文語で已然形に付く。
> ㋐原因・理由となる条件を示す。…ので。…だから。

This reading is only valid today in few idiomatic phrases, namely なれば (=であるので, なので) and ますれば (=ますので), both sound fairly quaint. Otherwise this kind of expression would never be used lest be confused with normal 仮定形 sense.

As for the interpretation of this sentence, その人唯一の存在 is a little problematic. Under this context, it is most naturally understood as "the unique existence of oneself", but the `N唯一` formula in principle should tell "only one that N has": 東京唯一の支店 "the only branch in Tokyo", 彼唯一のアルバム "his only album". In this light, the sentence may also be able to be read "because a person is always the only one for someone".

Comment: If you don’t mind, can you give me some example sentences for なれば with this sense?

Comment: @JimmyYang Just a random [Google Books](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=zwdWBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT147&lpg=PT147&source=bl&ots=_ni1htoapP&sig=ACfU3U2FtG1OB8LWQiF3IrY_FGuxIceIVA&hl=ja&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwif2Jex6Jr4AhU-pVYBHcxRDBwQ6AF6BAgzEAM) hit: 「わ、わが子**なれば**、ひらに御容赦を。あれも秀頼公より高禄を賜る身**なれば**、そうやすやすとは敵にはなびかぬと……」

Comment: Thank you. So do both 人 and その人 in the sentence 人は常に、その人唯一の存在でございますれば refer to the same person?

Comment: @chinoalpha If you take my first interpretation, then yes.